# Sort GS table by column values into new separate tabs

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

**What I am trying to achieve:**
I have a JIRA table output containing (aside of other columns) task name, story points and logged time.
Story points are meant to be a Scrum story point which defines complexity of a task by Fibonacci sequence (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...).

So output might be

| Task id | Story points | Worked (h) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 14 |
| 4 | 5 | 10 |

And my goal as to take a whole table from sheet (which can hold any number of records- 1, 50, 1000), select records with same story points and put them into separate tabs.

So there will be tabs named: Source, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...

Tab 1 will contain

| Task id | Story points | Worked (h) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 |

Tab 2 will contain

| Task id | Story points | Worked (h) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 14 |

etc.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow in GS? I would like to do that on end of every sprint (output data from Jira, past it in first tab and somehow trigger function which will sort these records for me)?

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query formula is all you need for each tab you create.

```
=QUERY(JiraData!A1:C, "where B=2",1)
```

Where `JiraData` is the name of your data tab, `B` is the column and `2` is the story points.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Hello, thanks for reponse. I've written the query as you suggested. `=QUERY(JIRASource, "SELECT A WHERE HV=1",1)`. Where "JIRASource" is name of tab with data, A is desired column and HV is column with story points stored (1,2,3). This particular query is for Tab holding 1 story point tasks. When I try to add this query to A1 cell, I am getting `#ERROR!` with message `formula parse error message`. Its same error when I use just "where ..." clause or when I specify select columns from sheet `JIRASource:A:C`

Comment: E: Problem (in my case, I do not know why it worked for you and not for me) was usage of commas. I had to use semicolons (;) between QUERY function arguments. After that change it worked as expected. Thank you for your help.